# Arbitrary transformation anchor (point) in QGraphicsView

Tags: anchor, transformation, qgraphicsview

The task is that I have some `GraphicsView` and I need to scale and rotate it not around the center of the View or Scene or the mouse pointer, but around an arbitrary point.

For example, I have a huge scene. With `LeftButton` click I place an anchor for transformation (a pin) to `mouseEvent.scenePos()`. And then, holding right mouse button and moving mouse I scale and rotate scene around that anchor, meaning pin staying still on the screen.
 That means I can't use `setTransformationAnchor` because it can accept only `transformationAnchor` enumeration.
 So how can I set transformation point?

Comment: Please share your code - it helps others to dig into your question appropriately. Also, visit - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic